# Url redirect with the username in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

I need  the link to be like this format http://localhost:32136/username/HomePage

Ex:-https://www.facebook.com/xxxyyyy

Kindly suggest me the link how to construct   the Url .I have configured the route.config as

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Profile",
    url: "{username}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Profile" },
    constraints: new { username = "Vinoth" }
);
```

Comment: Which list you will using? Can you please put here more code?

Comment: http://localhost:32136/username/HomePage   
User name will be vinoth for example how to do

Comment: I think this is URL and you will be get record from list?

Comment: Kindly REcheck my question was edited now..

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProfileRoute",
    url: "{username}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Profile" },
);
```

AccountController.cs

```
public ActionResult Profile(string username)
{
   if(username != "Vinoth")
       return HttpNotFound();   
   return View(username);
}
```

Comment: RouteConfig.cs

routes.MapRoute(
name: "ProfileRoute",
url: "{username}/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Profile" }
);

            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
  AccountController in apicontroller  
        public IHttpActionResult Profile(string username)
        {
            if (username != "Vinoth")
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(username);
        }

Comment: i have created AccountController.cs in a webapi contoller..its fine to use that one